# Selenium WD | Trying to use an 'If' statement with logical 'or'

Tags: css, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a step in my test that goes into several html pages and looks for an element on the screen. That element can have 2 different CSS class names while looking the same in the website (visually speaking) , I have to use an if statement with a logical 'or' to identify them

```
if (Status == driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".inlineblock.redClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-2")) || Status == driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".inlineblock.redClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-1")));
System.out.println("Stock is closed");)
```

I expected that if one of the 2 elements would appear, the Eclipse would

recognize it. Well - The second element out of the 2 appeared - and for some reason I've got an exception error. The if statement gave attention only to the first condition in the if, and ignored the second.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element:
>
> locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"**.inlineblock.redClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-2**"}Unable to

How can I make the || to work in this 'if' statement?
Thanks

[Screenshots of the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UF9G.png)

Comment: Put your **or** logic in your selector instead of trying to find both elements. However, this won't fully solve your problem, you need to search for how to determine if an element exists without throwing **NoSuchElement** in the case where neither of them exists.

Comment: What is `Status` in this case? If it's an already found element, which according to the above logic it would be, can't you just check the attributes of that?

Comment: if (Status == driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".inlineblock.redClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-2" ||".inlineblock.redClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-1" ))) 
*************************************

Eclipse shows a red line for that /=

The case is, that I have about 50 pages to test - and part of them have CSS_class1 and part of them have CSS_class2...I dont have any way to check which is which (Only manually)

And it is the same object on the screen, Looks exactly the same!

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for doing an `or` with a css selector. I haven't tested this but what you're looking for should be a `,` directly in your selector. Take a look at my solution, I had to fill in some blanks with what I think you're trying to do, let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your above logic, you have `Status` which is an already existing `WebElement` that you're comparing against another `Webelement` that you're looking up. I don't think this is what your intention was so I'm going to make some assumptions in a solution.

First: Find all of the elements that might exist with your desired selector (Note I'm using `findElements` instead of `findElement`)

```
List<WebElement> clockIconThingies = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".inlineblock.redClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-2, .inlineblock.redClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-1"));
```

Second: Check if that found anything

```
if(clockIconThingies.size() > 0)
{
    System.out.println("Stock is closed");
}
```

Alternatively for your css selector, from the image it looks like you might not need to do an **or** at all and just look for the class `redClockBigIcon` like this:

```
List<WebElement> clockIconThingies = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".redClockBigIcon"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !

-I copy/pasted it

for the first block I've got an error message below the 'Status' word & all the part that is to the right from the '=' (* I fixed the typo to 'Status')

1) Add cast to 'Webelement' 
2) change type of 'Status' to 'List<WebElement>

*******************************************************************************************
for the second block I've got an error below the 'Size' word:
1) Change cast to getZise(..)
2) Add cast to 'Status'

***********************************************************************************
What should I choose?

Comment: I'll check the added comment after you looked at me screenshot tomorrow morning and will update, appreciate it

Comment: It wasn't a typo, I have no idea what `Status` is and I can't make assumptions, so I declared a new variable `List<WebElement> status` with a lowercase `s` since that is convention for variables. If you have more information for what your version of `Status` is and how it's declared, that would be very helpful :) In the meantime, I'll change the variable name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry,couldn't wait....
It works !!! 

Thanks. I'll try to teach other when I'll get the hang of it.
It's a common class between the 2 scenarios....didn't notice /=
Love'ya dude!

Comment: You are amazing, Thanks...I tried to find a solution for so many hours...and its so simple....Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `try catch` block:

```
boolean isFirstElemPresent = true;

try{       
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".inlineblock.redClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-1"));    
}catch (NoSuchElementException e){
    isFirstElemPresent = false;
}

if(isFirstElemPresent == false)
     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".inlineblock.redClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-2"));
```

Or
To avoid `try catch` block, use below code snap:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("redClockBigIcon"));   

if (elements.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println("Element is not present");
} else {
    System.out.println("Element is present");
}
```

Comment: @dimaedunov check my answer if it is best fit of your need.